# How to switch between two .ui forms in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt4, qt-creator

I am using QtCreator and I need to create a program which when clicking a button in one (.ui) frame, changes focus to another (.ui) frame. How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Have you tried any of the examples which are installed with QtCreator?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest putting your two forms into different pages of a [QStackedWidget](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qstackedwidget.html), and setting the active widget based on which of the two you want to have visible.

Comment: do you have any small example or use full links for how to put forms in QStackedWidget and the Navigation between two forms

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the *activateWindow* method of QWidget.
[Link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#activateWindow)

I hope this helps other people coming here by google.